# I m trying to append multiple values to key in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read the file and converting it into dictionary .after reading i have to take a word and word first character as a key and word itself as a value. If another word with same character comes it should append the values to existing key itself.

```
import io 
file1 = open("text.txt")
line = file1.read()
words = line.split()
Dict={}
for w in words:
  if w[0] in Dict.keys():
      key1=w[0]
      wor=str(w)
      Dict.setdefault(key1,[])
      Dict[key1].append(wor)
  else:
    Dict[w[0]] = w
print Dict
```

Comment: What's the problem? What error ar you facing?

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**? For example, show us what your CSV file looks like as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54538764/edit).

Comment: Since `setdefault` returns the value of `Dict[key1]` (after setting it to `[]` if necessary), you can simply write `Dict.setdefault(key1, []).append(wor)`.

Comment: I've only had a quick glance, but since you're `append`ing to `Dict[key1]` it should be a list - therefore I think in the `else` you should have `Dict[w[0]] = [w]`?

Comment: That said, if `w[0]` is in `Dict.keys()`, then there's no need for `setdefault`; it's equivalent to `Dict[key1]` already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simplified your code. There is no point in having a else condition if using `set_default`

```
words = 'hello how are you'.split()
dictionary = {}
for word in words:
    key = word[0]
    dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(word)
print dictionary
```

In order to get rid of `set_default` use `default_dict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
words = 'hello how are you'.split()
dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    key = word[0]
    dictionary[key].append(word)
print dictionary.items()
```